# What size extension cord do I need to reach 200’ from the house to run 15A tools?

Tags: electrical, extension-cord

I need to work out in the woods (building a treehouse) with up to 15 Amp tools about 200 feet from the house. Obviously I should be using battery tools, but all of my tools are wired and I’d rather not buy battery versions of all my tools. What size extension cord(s) do I need to purchase?

Comment: At least 12 gauge, but for 200 ft a small(2000w) generator might be almost the same price.

Comment: More expensive to buy the generator on my quick look, for this distance. **Far more expensive** to **fuel** the generator than to pay your electric utility for the power.

Comment: Are you in a 110V or 220V country? Acceptable voltages loses are less in 110V countries

Comment: @CSM Questioner's profile says Oregon, so 120 VAC, 60 Hz, presumably.

Comment: No you should not use battery tools. They run out of battery at inconvenient times.

Comment: Modern battery tools store a lot of power, and you can buy more batteries. Depending on how many hours you plan to work at a stretch, batteries might be more cost-effective. You could also use a cheaper extension cord to power, say, a dewalt charger, and switch off.

Comment: @bmargulies to use a cheaper extension cord, the charger would need to use less power than the tool itself.  That implies it will take longer to charge a battery than to use it up.

Comment: @MarkRansom  most building tools are not running all the time, eg a drop saw spends about 70% of the time not cutting, and that's when it's being used.

Answer (score 10):

10 gauge (copper) would be a reasonable size - about 5% voltage drop on 120V at 15A. **Be sure you are plugged into a GFCI-protected outlet.**

*Pricing is off topic, local, goes out of date, yadda, yadda - current 2022 USA cost in the ballpark of slightly over $100 for a 100 foot 10Ga cord, so slightly over $200 for two of them.*

Comment: Romex and extension cords are different market segments. Prices were from this morning.

Comment: An outdoor outlet I think should be GFCI protected already to be up to code.  But if it isn't, there's a vast selection of GFCI circuits that can be plugged in inline.  Had never heard of one until I went looking.

Comment: We don't know that the OP has an outdoor outlet, or if their outdoor outlet, if present, has a GFCI. Depending on age of house, neither of things were required, until they were. Not hard to find people still running cords out a window. So, always best to specify. I have one of those 6 foot heavy duty GFCI extensions, and it's a good trick to have in the bag if you find yourself faced with a dubious place to plug in.

Comment: My whole house is wired with 12/2. Would plugging a 10/2 extension cord into a 12/2 fed outlet even work very well? Thinking of electricity like water, wouldn’t it be like having a 1/2” water pipe feeding a 1-1/2” pipe? The pressure would drop dramatically.

Comment: Not the way it works. Just minimizing the additional loss (voltage drop) from adding another 200 feet to the run inside your house, which is presumably much shorter if your name isn't Scrooge McDuck, or the modern equivalent (in which case I doubt you'd be DIY-ing it.)